# Duplicate key value violates unique constraint for primary key

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, eclipselink, primary-key

I have a problem where I get `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "my_obj_pk"`.
Where `my_obj_pk` is a primary key of a table mapped to Spring entity and based on `id`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "MY_TABLE")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "MY_OBJ_SEQ", allocationSize = 500)
public class MyObject {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "MY_OBJ_SEQ", strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
   private Long id;
...
}
```

The exception is:

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 1 INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (ID, ...) VALUES (257521, ...) was aborted: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "my_obj_pk"
  Detail: Key (id)=(257521) already exists.  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
Error Code: 0
Call: INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (ID, ...) VALUES (?, ...)
    bind => [8 parameters bound]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:524)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:757)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:726)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:478)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:272)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy341.saveMyObject(Unknown Source)
    at MyWorker.doWork(MyWorker.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run$$$capture(CompletableFuture.java:1626)
    ... 4 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.RollbackException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.3.v20180807-4be1041): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 1 INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (ID, ...) VALUES (257521, ...) was aborted: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "my_obj_pk"
  Detail: Key (id)=(257521) already exists.  Call getNextException to see other errors in the batch.
Error Code: 0
```

As you may see the JPA implementation is `Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.7.3.v20180807-4be1041`. The DB is PostgreSQl 9.4.0.

`MyWorker` is a Spring Component, that once in 10 minutes spawns 35 `CompletableFuture` objects that are run via executor having 20 threads. Each such `Future` multiple times calls various functions from 
Spring Service `MyServiceImpl`, where each function in the service is annotated with `Transactional` and `PermitAll`. These functions pull via different `Repository` various objects, say `X` and `Collection<Y>`,
part of these objects are created, if not exist already, however, not saved explicitly.

`X` has the following:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "xObj", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
List<MyObject> myObjects;
```

`Y` has the following:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "yObj", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)
List<MyObject> myObjects;
```

`MyObject` has:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "X_ID")
private X xObj;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "Y_ID")
private Y yObj;
```

So, basically, `X` and `Y` have a list of `MyObject` that have `X` and `Y` inside

At the end each `Future` calls `saveMyObject()` with `X` and `Collection<Y>` from the same `MyServiceImpl`:

```
@Override
@PermitAll
@Transactional
public void saveMyObject(X x, Collection<Y> colY) {
    xRepository.save(x);
    yRepository.save(colY);
    final List<MyObject> myObjects = x.getMyObjects() == null ?
            new ArrayList<>(colY.size()) : x.getMyObjects();
    colY.forEach(p -> {
        MyObject o = new MyObject();
        myObjects.add(o);
        List<MyObject> pobj = p.getMyObjects();
        if (pobj == null) {
           pobj = new ArrayList<>();
           p.setMyObjects(pobj);
        }
        pobj.add(o);
    });
    x.setMyObjects(myObjects);
    myObjectsRepository.save(myObjects);
}
```

There is NO manual assignment of IDs anywhere...
As of now, I don't get how the PK of MyObject may be duplicated. I prefer, if possible, not to touch `CASCADE` properties, as these classes exist for a long time
and are used widely. Thanks!

Edit: I should add that different `Future` may work on the same `Y` and `MyObject` , so, probably, the design is not quite right

Comment: You are using table generation, which requires a transaction to read and increment the values within the table. If you turn on SQL logging, you should see what is happening, but chances are that you have not setup a connection pool for your sequence so that it can have its own transaction outside independent of your application transaction. See https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/concepts/data_access006.htm#CHDEFJHH

Comment: @Chris Much thanks, will check this in a couple of days, when I'm done with the current assignment